# What determines the powers a Super gets?

Tags: the-boys-2019

We learn that in the universe of *The Boys* that superheros gain their powers by a chemical compound created by Frederick Vought known as Compound V. We see all different types of powers super strength, super speed, talking to marine life, energy based, limb regeneration, a huge penis...

So what about Compound V allows for this vast range of abilities? Is it an additive to the compound that is specifically chosen or is some reaction between the Compound V and the subject's DNA? Either way is it possible to know what powers a specific subject will obtain or is it just luck-of-the-draw?

<sub>Looking for answers specific the television series, but if no answer is provided there I am also willing to accept answers from the source comics.</sub>

Comment: In the comics, the Boys drink a modified version of Compound V and it seems to give them all super-strength only.

Comment: In the comics, it was injected into little Huey. MM got it from his mother; I think he was the only one who drank it. No idea of the Frenchman's powers. The female was an experiment. Huey and Butcher had both increased strength and some level of invulnerability.

Comment: In the comics, it is implied that it is part of the exact compound V formulation + additives and blind luck. Impure compound V is everywhere in the ecosystem, so often people get "poisoned" with it, giving their children "powers". Well, lucky ones get powers. Unlucky ones mutate and die young (It happened to MM's brother). Pure compound V, depending on the dosage and formulation, can give somebody everything from temporary to long term powers. Some prostitutes take weaker version of V for temporary superstrength boost to be able to survive sex with supers.

Comment: So,the main question is, do you accept comics as valid source of info or only show?

Comment: We see a group of kids all of the same age being given equal doses of Compound V (from the same source) in the comics. Their powers seem to be entirely random.